# rosmake fails for youbot_description

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, youbot, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get a simulated youBot running in Gazebo.
When running rosmake on the line

*rosmake youbot_description*

I get a failure. The failure states

*[rosmake-7] Finished <<< youbot_description [FAIL] [ 2.11 seconds ]

[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package youbot_description.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:

[ rosmake ] Built 41 packages with 1 failures.

[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory

[ rosmake ] /home/ros-root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121213-115221*

I downloaded using the apt-get commands from this page:
http://youbot-store.com/simulation/12/software.aspx

But I did substitute to use ros-fuerte-pr2-controllers and ros-fuerte-pr2-simulator as I am running fuerte.

I can post the log file if needed but here's the portion that seems to be relevant:

*[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cartesian_compliance_control_test.dir/examples/cartesian_compliance_control_test.o
/home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_common/youbot_description/examples/cartesian_compliance_control_test.cpp: In function ‘void publishTf()’:
/home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_common/youbot_description/examples/cartesian_compliance_control_test.cpp:66:67: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘tf::Quaternion&’ from expression of type ‘btQuaternion’
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:105:20: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘void tf::quaternionMsgToTF(const Quaternion&, tf::Quaternion&)’
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/cartesian_compliance_control_test.dir/examples/cartesian_compliance_control_test.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_common/youbot_description/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cartesian_compliance_control_test.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_common/youbot_description/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ros-root/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/ros_stacks/youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_common/youbot_description/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2*

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50395/rosmake-fails-for-youbot_description/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Switching rosdistros does not necessarily compile.  You need to fix the bullet compile issues.  It's documented in the [release notes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bullet/ChangeList)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1